# Changing the default route of a mean-stack package

Tags: javascript, routes, mean-stack

I am working on a custom MEAN package and cannot figure out how to change the default route from index.html to the page I choose.  When added, the package creates a "Books" shortcut in the navbar of the default home page.  When clicked this goes to the default **index.html** page, when I want it to go to the custom **list.html**.

I considered copying and pasting **list.html** into **index.html**, but I'm worried that this may cause issues elsewhere.  Where can I find the page in a MEAN package to change the default route?

I'm hoping to be able to edit the home page on a larger scale, hopefully by figuring out first how to change this default route.  I need to be able to edit the text that links to **index.html**, as well as remove other things.  I've viewed this code in Inspect Element, but cannot figure out where it is located (as an html, controller, etc) so I can change it.

**../route/books.js**

```
'use strict';

var books = require('../controllers/books');

// Book has authorization helpers
var hasAuthorization = function(req, res, next) {
  if (!req.user.isAdmin && req.book.user.id !== req.user.id) {
    return res.status(401).send('User is not authorized');
  }
  next();
};

// The Package is past automatically as first parameter
module.exports = function(Books, app, auth, database) {

  app.route('/books')
    .get(books.all)
    .post(auth.requiresLogin, books.create);
  app.route('/books/:bookId')
    .get(auth.isMongoId, books.show)
    .put(auth.isMongoId, auth.requiresLogin, hasAuthorization, books.update)
    .delete(auth.isMongoId, auth.requiresLogin, hasAuthorization, books.destroy);

  // Finish with setting up the articleId param
  app.param('bookId', books.book);
};
```

Comment: Please show the code for the `books` controller.